# JQuery Event not firing after being attached

Tags: jquery, razor

Ok, I'm using Razor and jquery 1.5.1 if that affects the answer.

I have some simple jquery I copied from another post on this site. I have a variable number of sections that are rendered using the Razor engine.

I want to be able to hide / display the data under each section (which is wrapped in a div.)

so the HTML is

```
<div>Course 1<a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Click</a>
<div class="contentHidden" style="display:none;"> content here </div></div>
<div>Course 2<a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Click</a>
<div class="contentHidden" style="display:none;"> content here </div></div>
```

And the jquery is;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".toggle").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children("div").toggle();
  });
});
```

The jquery is at the bottom of the view, and I have added in the `document.ready` bit to ensure that the `<a>` tags do exist.

One thing I have considered is that I am creating the page content using the razor `@foreach()`, however that must happen at the server before the content is streamed to the browser, so I don't believe that I am doing this before the  links are created, and shouldn't need to use live or a delegate.

But I'm stuck now, so can anyone suggest how I can track this down (or better yet fix it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `a` elements don't have a `div` child. Instead, it is the next element:

```
$(this).next("div").toggle();
```

Visually the `div` may be under the `a` element. However, what matters is the DOM structure, in which the `div` is a sibling of the `a`.

Comment: Damn, I just shut the dev PC down. I'll check this first thing in the morning, and if it works hide my head in shame and give you a tick, thanks. I even made sure I wrapped the content inside the main div for that reason, and didn't spot the obvious :$.

Thanks again!

Comment: `$(this).siblings('.contentHidden').toggle()` would also be an option, if the div you want to hide isn't always the next element

Comment: Yup. The `div` is not within the `a`, therefore it is not a child.